# Data wrangling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
data = {
    'id' :    [1, 1,1,1, 2, 2,2,2],
    'Weight':   [200, 200, 400, 400, 200, 200, 400, 400],
    'CODE':     ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'D':   [1,2,1,2,7, 3, 2, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My dataframe is above my final output is simplified dictionary from this.

1. I want to group by id and sum “D”
2. I want to have sum of weight, corresponding to unique ‘Code’ (in above example it would be 200 + 400 = 600)

I am able to do 1, this way:

```
docs = df[['id', ‘D’]].groupby(['id']).sum().reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary for `sum` and remove duplicates with `np.sum`:

```
docs = df.groupby('id').agg({'D':'sum', 'Weight': lambda x: np.sum(x.unique())}).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Or:

```
docs = df.groupby('id').agg({'D':'sum', 'Weight': lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().sum()}).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

---

```
print (docs)
[{'id': 1, 'D': 6, 'Weight': 600}, {'id': 2, 'D': 13, 'Weight': 600}]
```